# Command substitution in fish

Tags: fish

I'm trying to migrate this working command

```
docker-compose $(find docker-compose* | sed -e "s/^/-f /") up -d --remove-orphans
```

from bash to fish. The intention of this command is to get this

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.backups.yml ... -f docker-compose.wiki.yml up -d --remove-orphans
```

My naive try

```
docker-compose (find docker-compose* | sed -e "s/^/-f /") up -d --remove-orphans
```

is not working, though. The error is:

```
ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './ docker-compose.backups.yml'
```

What is the correct translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in behavior is due to the fact fish, sanely, only splits the output of a command capture on line boundaries. Whereas POSIX shells like bash split it on whitespace by default. That is, POSIX shells split the output of `$(...)` on the value of `$IFS` which is space, tab, and newline by default.

There are several ways to rewrite that command so it works in fish. The one that requires the smallest change is to change the sed to insert a newline between the `-f` and the filename:

```
docker-compose (find docker-compose* | sed -e "s/^/-f\n/") up -d --remove-orphans
```